# How to write multiple solutions in set builder notation?

Tags: notation

I am across this problem
$$\cos(2v)=\cos(4v)$$ Where $$0\le v \le \pi$$

I know how to solve it, I was just wondering how you would write all the solutions in efficient set builder notation so I don't waste time and paper, especially on a test. I've come across similar problems before where there was a significant number of solutions, around a dozen. And it took a long time calculating and writing each one. Let it be known I'm not very familiar with set builder notation, I just know how to read them at a basic level. So forgive my probably faulty attempt in writing one below.

I was thinking something like: $$v \in \left\{x \mid x = \pi n \mid n \in \left\{0,1 \right\} \right\} $$
I'm trying to say "$v$ is equal to $\pi n$ where $n$ is a whole number that is either $0$ or $1$. This is most likely wrong, and I'm obviously missing another set of solutions, but I'm just trying to explain what it is that I am after.

Comment: So if I get you correctly then you want to write $\{0,\pi\}$. This is the shortest way, and there's no need for set builder notation here. If you insist on set builder notation (which seems unnecessary and overly complicated here), then you could write it as $\{\pi n | n\in\{0,1\}\}$.

Comment: @Snaw I realize ${0,π}$ is the shortest way, but like i said, there are similar problems where the solutions are MANY. Take $\sin(3v) = \sin(6v)$ for example. It has 9 different solutions. But the solutions are elements of two sets respectively and both these sets have a patern to them. One is $v = \frac{2\pi n}{-3}$ and the other is $v = \frac{\pi + 2\pi n}{9}$. Each of them constrained with $0 \le v \le \pi$. So there must a way to write all of this more efficiently.

Comment: I'd probably write that as $\{\frac{2\pi n}{-3} | n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{\frac{\pi+2\pi n}{9} | n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. (It should be possible to make some algebraic gymnastics and add another variable and write the result as a single set rather than the union of two sets-- but it would not be worth it, as the result would definitely be far less readable than the more honest version of the union of two sets.)

Comment: @Snaw How would you apply the condition $0\le v \le \pi$ on that?

Comment: I'd find the constraint in terms of $n$ for each of them. For instance if for the first one you get that $n$ is a natural number between $1$ and $5$ (just made up a number for the purpose of illustartion) then you could write the first set $\{\frac{2\pi n}{-3}|n\in \{1,\cdots,5\}\}$ and maybe a better way to write this is $\{\frac{2\pi n}{-3}|n\in\mathbb{N},n\leq 5\}$.

Comment: @Snaw You know, you pretty much answered my question. Why didn't you just write an answer? I would have accepted it haha. I know we're supposed to avoid "thank you"s in the comments, but thank you nonetheless.

Comment: Great, you're welcome.